# Takes long time while building image on python wit messaage : Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running

Tags: python, pandas

i have problem while building docker image on python :
below execution process takes long time around 20 minutes:

```
Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml): still running...
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=80"]
```

`requirement.txt`:

```
fastapi
uvicorn
pydantic[dotenv]
requests
python-dotenv==0.19.2
pandas==1.4.3
numpy==1.24.2
scikit-learn==1.2.2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no [building wheel](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.4.3/#files) for `Pandas==1.4.3` and `Python==3.11` so the fallback is to download the source archive (`pandas-1.4.3.tar.gz`) and build it from scratch. You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade your python version from 3.11 to 3.10 in `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10.10-buster
```

2. Upgrade the pandas version from 1.4.3 to 1.5.3 in `requirements.txt`:

```
pandas==1.5.3
```

In both cases `(Python 3.10, Pandas 1.4)` or `(Python 3.11, Pandas 1.5)`, there is no compilation time with your requirements.

Comment: FROM python:3.10.10-buster solves my problem, thanks